# printing [mysql_query] result in a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to print mysql_query result in a table. I know how to do it but I am just confused. I tried this.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Could not Connect.");
mysql_select_db("check") or die("Could not Select DB");
$table = "cc";
$i = 1;
$query = "select * from $table";
$sql = mysql_query($query);
if($sql){
echo "<table border='5'><tr>";
while($i<=2 && $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<td>" . $row[id] . " : " .  $row[name] . "</td>";
++$i;
}
echo "</tr><tr>";
while($i<=4 && $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<td>" . $row[id] . " : " .  $row[name] . "</td>";
++$i;
}
echo "</tr><tr>";
while($i<=6 && $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<td>" . $row[id] . " : " .  $row[name] . "</td>";
++$i;
}
echo "</tr><tr>";
while($i<=8 && $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<td>" . $row[id] . " : " .  $row[name] . "</td>";
++$i;
}
echo "</tr><tr>";
echo "</tr></table>";
}

?>
```

As you can see it is written again and again with a slight change of 2,4,6,8 in the while loop. It works but the problem is I cant rewrite it again and again as when the website will go live it will have more than 1000 entries. Could You guys help me out by suggesting another way to do this?

---

""**** I need it to be like these dots (dots represent records in the database) ****"""

```
                        . . . .

                        . . . .

                        . . . .
```

---

THANKS in Advance.
Ramzy

Comment: What is `i` ? The number of rows? Have you tried using a for loop with mysql_num_rows ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Comment: Please go back to programming basics and [read](http://www.php.net/manual/de/control-structures.while.php) [about](http://www.teamten.com/lawrence/programming/intro/intro8.html) [loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow#Loops).

Comment: $i is just a variable that is used to tell the loop to stop when it reaches to max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I Got The Answer.. I wanted it to be like this. I made this and It Actually Works.**

---

```
<?php
$i = 1;
mysql_connect("localhost" , "root" , "") or die('Could not Connect.');
mysql_select_db("db") or die('Could not select DB.');
$query = "select * from `check`";
$sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<table border='5' width='50%'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Gender</th></tr></table><table border='5' width='50%'><tr>";
if($i<3){
echo "<td align='center'>".$row['name']."</td>";
echo "<td align='center'>".$row['gender']."</td>";
++$i;
} else {
echo "<td align='center'>".$row['name']."</td><td align='center'>".$row['gender']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
$i = 1;
echo "<tr>";
}
}
echo "</table>";
?>
</div>
```

---

**Thank You Guys For Your Support**

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Could not Connect.");
    mysql_select_db("check") or die("Could not Select DB");
    $table = "cc";
    $query = "select * from $table";
    $sql = mysql_query($query);

    if($sql){
        echo "<table border='5'><tr>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . " : " .  $row['name'] . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr></table>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks.... but it will print it in columns but I need it to print in rows and column as well..

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . " : " .  $row['name'] . "</td>";
}
```

I don't really see what's the problem here.
By the way you should never call you're array like this `$row[id]` but you should quote the key instead `$row['id'];` Because if a constant id exists it will screw up your code and also for performance reason.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
$limit = 1000;//place any value you need here to limit the number of rows displayed
while ($i<=$limit && $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . " : " .  $row['name'] . "</td>";
    ++$i;
}
```

Also, that limit is unnecessary if all you want is to flush every record to the output. You could just do

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . " : " .  $row['name'] . "</td>";
}
```

And it will stop as soon as there are no more records.

Comment: Or use the SQL `LIMIT 0, 1000` instead…

Comment: thanks...but that's not the problem. the problem is I need it to print in rows and columns

Answer (score 0):

To print all database rows into an HTML-table, use:

```
echo '<table>';
$i = 0; // $i is just for numbering the output, not really useful
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo '<tr><td>' . $i . ' - ' . $row['id'] . ' : ' . $row['name'] . '</td></tr>';
    $i++;
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

Comment: thanks.... I know it but the problem is it will print in rows but I need it to print in rows and column as well..

Answer (score 0):

here is a general function I use:

```
function query_result_to_html_table($res, $table_id = NULL, $table_class = NULL, $display_null = true)
{
    $table = array();
    while ($tmp = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
            array_push($table, $tmp);

    if (!count($table))
            return false;

    echo "<table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" "
                    . ($table_id ? "id=\"$table_id\" " : "")
                    . ($table_class ? "class=\"$table_class\" " : "") . ">";
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach (array_keys($table[0]) as $field_name) {
            echo "<th>$field_name";
    }

    foreach ($table as $row) {
            echo "<tr>";
            foreach ($row as $col => $value) {
                    echo "<td>";
                    if ($value === NULL)
                            echo "NULL";
                    else
                            echo $value;
            }
            echo "\n";
    }
    echo "</table>\n";
    return true;
}
```